# Nonzero digits in n!

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can it be shown that a positive fraction of the base-$b$ digits of n! are nonzero (in the limit as $n\to\infty$)?

Comment: The answer: $9/10$ of course but even $> 0$ is most possibly unprovable presently. I asked a similar question about powers of an integer (say, $3$) here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38971/sums-of-digits-of-powers-of-integers (see Update 4 in that question).   

Comment: I meant $(b-1)/b$, of course.

Comment: i.e. $\ 9 := 10-1,\ $ whatever $\ 10\ $ would be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bound given by F. Luca and cited in Gjergji Zaimi's answer has been recently improved, although only by a factor $\log \log \log n$. Precisely, in *C. Sanna, [On the sum of digits of the factorial](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2014.09.003), J. Number Theory 147 (2015), 836--841*, the author proved that
$$\min\{s_b(n!),s_b(\Lambda_n)\} > c_b \log n \log \log \log n , $$
for all integers $n > e^e$, where $s_b(\cdot)$ is the sum of base-$b$ digits function, $c_b > 0$ is a constant depending only on $b$, and $\Lambda_n$ is the least common multiple of $1, \ldots, n$. Clearly, this inequality also holds with $s_b$ replaced by $t_b$, i.e., the function counting the number of non-zero base-$b$ digits of its argument, since $t_b(m) \geq s_b(m)/b$ for each positive integer $m$.

Answer (score 14):

I believe the best current lower bound on this is the one given by F. Luca in ["The Number of Non-Zero Digits of n!"](http://math.ca/10.4153/CMB-2002-013-9) Canad. Math. Bull. 45(2002), 115-118. It is proven there that the number of non-zero base $b$ digits grows at least as fast as $C_b\log n$.

Comment: Interesting! It is better than the current lower bound for $a^n$ (where $a$ is co-prime with 10). 