# Average digit sum in different bases

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given two natural numbers $n\geq 1$ and $b\geq 2$, denote by $S_b(n)$ the sum of the digit of $n$ in its representation in base $b$. Clearly $S_b(n)$ varies from 1 (when $n$ is a power of $b$) to $(b-1)\lfloor\ln{n}/\ln{b}\rfloor$  (when $n=b^k-1$ for some integer $k$). However, for a fixed $n$, the value of $S_b(n)$ for a generic base $b$ should be of order $(b-1)/2\cdot\ln{n}/\ln{b}$.

This lead to consider the average of $S_b(n)$ for $b\leq n$

$$S(n):=\sum_{b\leq n}S_b(n)$$
or (maybe better) the wieghted average
$$S_w(n):=\sum_{b\leq n}\frac{S_b(n)}{b}$$

There exists some asymptotics or non trivial bounds for $S(n)$ and $S_w(n)$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Numerics suggest that $S(n) \sim Cn^2$ for some constant $C$ between $0.175$ and $0.18$.

Note that the bases $\frac n2<b\le n$ are easy to calculate: we get a sequence of two-digit numbers of the form $1x$, where $x$ runs from $\frac n2$ or so to $0$ (covering all integers in between). The sum of all these digits is asymptotic to $\frac12(\frac n2)^2$.

In the next range $\frac n3<b\le \frac n2$, we get a sequence of two-digit numbers of the form $2x$, where $x$ hits every other integer between about $\frac n3$ and $0$. The sum of all these digits is asymptotic to $\frac22(\frac n6)^2$.

Continuing to look at these ranges, we get a sequence of contributions of the form $\frac k2(\frac n{k(k+1)})^2$ from the bases $\frac n{k+1}<b\le\frac nk$ (at least until $k$ is about $\sqrt n$ or so). And one can calculate that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac k2\bigg(\frac 1{k(k+1)}\bigg)^2 = 1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} = 0.17753...
$$

So I'm guessing that one can prove in this way that $S(n) \sim (1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})n^2$.

(Numerically $S_w(n)$ seems to have size $n$, perhaps asymptotic to $Dn$ with some constant $D$ between $0.43$ and $0.44$. The similar heuristic doesn't give such a formula, however, because the large bases don't dominate the sum to the same extent as for $S(n)$.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The asymptotic for $S(n)$ seems indeed true. Can we say something about the error term? Anyway  the weighted version $S_w(n)$ looks more interesenting, because (as you pointed out) the major contribution is given only by small bases. Supposing $S_w(n)$ asymptotic  to $Dn$, what can we say about the error term?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the major contribution is from the small bases - only that the large bases don't completely dominate. In a random heuristic, the contribution from the base $b$ is roughly $(\log n)/(2\log b)$; so there's not too much difference between the contributions of the small and large $b$, compared to the scale of the answer. Anyway, to answer your question: I doubt there's anything (outside generic guesses) one could say about the error term until one identifies the constnat $D$.

Comment: The question if $S_w(n)$ actually admits an asymptotic of the form $Dn$ seems very interesting. Do you have some suggestion for such result to be true?

Answer (score 13):

The observation by Greg Martin is indeed correct. I have worked with these expressions in my bachelor thesis, which can be accessed for free here:

[Fissum, Robin. Digit sums and the number of prime factors of the factorial $n!=1\cdot 2\cdots n$, NTNU (2020)](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/handle/11250/2980249).

Proposition 2.10, page 12 states that $$\sum_{2\leq b\leq n}S_b(n)\sim (1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})n^2$$
as $n \to \infty$.

### Relationship between the two sums

We have
$$\sum_{2\leq b\leq n}\frac{S_b(n)}{b}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{2\leq b\leq n}S_b(n)+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sum \limits_{2 \leq b \leq x}S_b(n)}{x^2}dx$$

Proof:

Set $n_0$ equal to a fixed positive integer, and consider the sum $\sum \limits_{2\leq b\leq n}\frac{S_b(n_0)}{b}$. If we let $(a_k)_{k=1,2,\ldots}$ be the sequence defined by $a_1=0$ and $a_t=S_t(n_0)$ for $t\geq 2$, and $\phi:t\mapsto\frac{1}{t}$. Then the sum becomes $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k\phi(k)$, which by Abel's summation formula equals
$$\phi(n)\sum_{k=1}^na_k -\int_{1}^{n}\phi'(x)\sum_{k\leq x}a_k \;\;dx$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{2\leq b\leq n}S_b(n_0)+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sum \limits_{2 \leq b \leq x}S_b(n_0)}{x^2}dx$$
Setting $n_0$ equal to $n$ completes the proof.

### Asymptotic formula for the second sum

Proposition 4.4, page 27 states that $$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sum \limits_{p \leq n}S_p(n)}{x^2}dx \sim (\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\gamma)\frac{n}{\log(n)},$$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler- Mascheroni constant. Here, the summation is taken over the primes $p$. If you modify the deduction of this formula, you could conclude that
$$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sum \limits_{2 \leq b \leq x}S_b(n)}{x^2}dx \sim (\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\gamma)n$$
Using the relationship we obtained for the two summands, along with these two asymptotic formulae, we get:
\begin{align}
\sum_{2\leq b\leq n}\frac{S_b(n)}{b}\;=&\;\frac{1}{n}\sum_{2\leq b\leq n}S_b(n)+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sum \limits_{2 \leq b \leq x}S_b(n)}{x^2}dx 
\\ \sim \; &(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})n+(\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\gamma)n \\[2mm]
\sim \; &(1-\gamma)n & \\[2mm]
=&\; n \cdot 0.42278433\ldots
\end{align}
Which perfectly matches the the numerical heuristics as pointed out by Greg Martin.

### What if we sum over only primes p?

Proposition 2.12(p.14), Propostion 4.4(p.27) and the forumlae on page 25 show that

\begin{align}\sum_{p \leq n}S_p(n)\; =\; &(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})\frac{n^2}{\log(n)}+C\frac{n^2}{\log^2(n)}+o(\frac{n^2}{\log^2(n)}) \\
\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{S_p(n)}{p}\sim& \;(1-\gamma)\frac{n}{\log(n)},
\end{align}

where $C=0.119\ldots$

Comment: Well done, very nice job!

Comment: Happy to be of help : )

Answer (score 4):

Check out [the closely related article by L. E. Bush](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2304217.pdf?acceptTC=true) from the 1940 American Math Monthly. Bush shows that for $r$ fixed, and $n < N,$ the average value of digit sums is asymptotic to:
$$
\frac{(r-1) \log N}{2 \log r}.
$$